# Mysql Query Combination

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which is combined from 3 tables a,b,c, the problem here is the table c is present in 2 databases D1 AND D2 , so I have to fetch the records from both Databases for table c .Table a and b are from database D1 alone,

The query is:

```
$strQuery="SELECT a.id, b.lastname, school " ."FROM D1.a,D1.b" .
    " WHERE a.idint = (select c_idint from D1.c where Cid IN(10) 
UNION select c_idint from D2.c where Cid IN(10) order by c_idint)
 AND a.idint = b.idb";
```

The issue is the field 'school' is from table c, if i avoid the field 'school' from query it works fine, but I have to fetch field 'school' too, How can I modify the query.  Thanks:)

Comment: use `AS` to alias your `D1.c` table to something else

Comment: *That's* the issue? What about all the other rubbish going on in this query - what if the subquery returns an array, and what's with the stops and starts (".")?

Comment: @Strawberry, think before you yell please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$strQuery="SELECT a.id, b.lastname, c.school as dSchool, '' as ddSchool " ."FROM D1.a,D1.b, D1.c" .
    " WHERE a.idint = c.idint AND c.Cid IN (10)
 AND a.idint = b.idb

UNION 

SELECT a.id, b.lastname, '' as dSchool, c.school as ddSchool " ."FROM D1.a,D1.b, D2.c" .
    " WHERE a.idint = c.idint AND c.Cid IN (10)
 AND a.idint = b.idb
";
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html),

```
$strQuery="SELECT a.id, b.lastname, D2.c.school as school1,D1.c.school as school2 " ."FROM D1.a,D1.b,D1.c,d2.c" .
          " WHERE a.idint = (select c_idint from D1.c where Cid IN(10) 
          UNION select c_idint from D2.c where Cid IN(10) order by c_idint)
          AND a.idint = b.idb";
```

Comment: there should be a `from table c` portion also in query right but its from 2 databases

Comment: What error ? And I direct you to the way, may you want to change the db or table name in my query.

Comment: not error, but i need both table c derived from D1 AND D2 to act as one table, not seperately displaying records. THanks

Answer (score 0):

give a try like this:-

```
$strQuery="SELECT a.id, b.lastname, c.school " ."FROM D1.a,D1.b,D1.c" .
 " WHERE a.idint = (select c_idint from D1.c where Cid IN(10) 
UNION select c_idint,school from D2.c where Cid IN(10) order by c_idint)
AND a.idint = b.idb";
```

Comment: but table c is fetched from 2 databses D1 and D2

Comment: @YipManWingChun in query school is fetched from both the databases D1 and D2

Comment: no , you have given query as ""FROM D1.a,D1.b,D1.c""  there isnt D2.c   ?